# Meaning of NEXT in Linked List creation in perl

Tags: perl, linked-list

So I am trying to learn Linked Lists using Perl. I am reading [*Mastering Algorithms with Perl*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923980.do) by Jon Orwant. In the book he explains how to create a linked list.
I understand most of it, but I just simply fail to understand the command/index/key `NEXT` in the second last line of the code snippet.

```
$list=undef;
$tail=\$list;

foreach (1..5){
  my $node = [undef, $_ * $_];
  $$tail = $node;
  $tail = \${$node->[NEXT]}; # The NEXT on this line? 
}
```

What is he trying to do there?

Is `$node` a scalar, which stores the address of the unnamed array? Also even if we are dereferencing `$node`, should we not refer to the individual elements by an index number, such as (0,1). If we do use `NEXT` as a key, is `$node` a reference to a hash?
I am very confused.

Something in plain English will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NEXT` is a constant, declared earlier in the script.  It contains an integer value representing the index of the current node's member element that refers to the *next* node.

Under this scheme, each node is a small anonymous array.  One element of this anonymous array contains the payload, and the other contains a reference pointing to the next node.

If you look at some of the earlier examples in that chapter you will see the following declarations:

```
use constant NEXT    => 0;
use constant VAL     => 1;
```

So `$node->[NEXT]` is synonymous to `$node->[0]`, which contains a reference to the next node in the linked list chain, while `$node->[VAL]` is synonymous with `$node->[1]`; the value (or payload) stored in the current node.

I'll comment on the code snippet you provided:

```
foreach (1..5){
  my $node = [undef, $_ * $_];    # Create a new node as an anon array.

  # Set the previous node's "next node reference" to point to this new node.
  $$tail = $node;                 

  # Remember a reference to the new node's "next node reference" element.
  # So that it can be updated when another new element is added on next iteraton.
  $tail = \${$node->[NEXT]}; # The NEXT on this line? 
}
```

Excellent book, by the way.  I've got several algorithms books, and that one continues to be among my favorites after all these years.

**Update:** I do agree that the book isn't a model of current idiomatic Perl, or current "best practices" Perl, but do feel it is a nice resource for gaining an understanding of the application of classic algorithms with Perl.  I still refer back to it from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

`NEXT` is a constant, declared on an earlier page, that contains a number.  Its being used instead of just the regular number to access the array ref `$node` so the reader knows that slot is where the next element in the linked list is stored.

It's a technique to use array references to store things other than lists.  The technique was intended to save memory and CPU time compared to using a hash reference.  In reality it doesn't make much performance difference and its awkward to work with.  The book is quite a bit out of date in its ideas about how to write Perl code.  Use a hash reference instead.

```
my $list;
my $tail = \$list;
foreach my $num (1..5) {
    my $node = { data => $num };
    $$tail = $node;
    $tail = \$node->{next};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, should we have another key->value pair to store the next node address. The name of the key being "next"?

Comment: @seleniumnewbie Yes, that's what `$node->{next}` is.

Comment: Also i changed `$tail = \${$node->{next}};` to `$tail = \$node->{next};` :) or it leads to a whole lotta confusion