# Deleting the head of a linked list does not main the hash structure?

Tags: perl, hash, linked-list

Yet another data structure doubt. I will get straight to it.
This is what I have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $head= undef;
my $tail=\$head;

open FILE, "<datastored.txt" or die $!;

while (<FILE>){
    my $node = {
                "data" => $_ , 
                "next" => undef
            };
    $$tail=$node; 
    $tail = \${$node->{"next"}}; 
};

# #1# Print full list #
print Dumper $head;

# #2# Delete the first node and display data of next node #
$head = $head->{next};
my $value = $head->{data};
```

and this is the output I get

```
$VAR1 = {
          'next' => \{
                        'next' => \{
                                      'next' => \{
                                                    'next' => \undef,
                                                    'data' => 'line 4'
                                                  },
                                      'data' => 'line 3
'
                                    },
                        'data' => 'line 2
'
                      },
          'data' => 'line 1
'
        };
Not a HASH reference at linkedlist.pl line 32, <FILE> line 4. **<<<< My Problem and hence my question?**
```

Note - the content of the file `datastored.txt` is simply

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

If I look at the print result of `$head` initially, it clearly is a hash within a hash and so on, so why is that after deleting the first node is the integrity of the data structure hampered? *(See Error on last line of output)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perl references are tricky.  The dumper output notation `\{` is showing that the `{next}` fields contain references to references to hashes.

The offending line is the update to `tail`.  Try

```
$tail = \$node->{"next"};
```

Comment: O yes I see that now, so my follow up question would be, How do i get the value of the second node, and for any node of my choice?

Comment: With the code change I posted, the extra level of references goes away, and your code to access the second item works fine.

Comment: Yeah I understand now, linked lists are killing me! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two things, (1) its not home work, I am trying to learn Linked lists(check my profile) and see the questions, I am progressively getting stuck and need someone to help, I would consider my self lucky if I had some one giving me homework (cause the teacher would teach me eventually). I am referring "O'Reilly -Mastering Algos with Perl". (2) I appreciate you correcting the solution with your previous comment, but the solution provided by Gene worked and dint understand why not to make scalar references?

Answer (score 3):

> it clearly is a hash within a hash and so on

Actually, it's clearly not. Each next holds a reference to a reference to a hash, not a reference to a hash. Notice all the "`\`"? You should be seeing

```
$VAR1 = {
  'next' => {
    'next' => {
      'next' => {
        'next' => undef,
        'data' => 'line 4'
      },
      'data' => 'line 3'
    },
    'data' => 'line 2'
  },
  'data' => 'line 1'
};
```

Comment: So how do i get the value out?

Comment: `$head = $head->{next};` is correct. The error is creating all those references to references to hashes in the first place.

Comment: isn that how i should create Linked Lists see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940533/meaning-of-next-in-linked-list-creation-in-perl/10940796#10940796

Comment: Nope. As your data dump shows, you got a slew of useless references to references to hashes. You shouldn't be seeing those "`\ `" in the dump.

Comment: Yeah I understand now, linked lists are killing me! Thanks for your help.